# How to check if user defined functions is missing on the file from which it was imported using pylance?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm refactoring a large codebase. And I have migrated many function here and there.

I want to filter pylint output to show me error like `my_function` doesn't exist in `helper.py` function anymore.

```py
# ------ Before refactor ------

# File helper.py
def my_function():
    pass

# File controller.py
from my_module.helper import my_function
```

After refactor, let's say `my_function()` has been moved to a new file `utils.py` instead.
How can I observe such errors using pylint ?

I'm using `pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')` command to run linting on project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Pylance is only a static code analysis tool and this error only occurs during runtime. So, not possible.